# Javascript, calling function

Tags: javascript, function, global-variables

from previous help I am using something like this:

```
(function (global) {

  // your code here

  global.myGlobalVar = myVar

}(this));
```

which works great for variables, but how do I do it for functions?

For example I tried this:

```
(function (global) {

  function something()
{
// do something, return something
}

  global.something()= something();

}(this));
```

but that does not work :(

How do I get it to work with functions?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Please note that this is being called in a html page, first I do this:

```
<script language="Javascript" src="four.js">
```

then

```
<body onload="javascript:something()">
```

Comment: You have to realize that functions are just values like anything else. You can refer to them with their name and call them by adding parenthesis after their name.

Comment: In `onload`, you should not write `javascript:` (it is sometimes used in `<a href="">`). You just simply write the function name you want to execute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to *declare* a function, you should not *execute* it. So remove `()`.

```
(function (global) {

  function something()
{
// do something, return something
}

  global.something = something; // something is the variable
                                // containing the function and
                                // you store it into global


}(window));
```

Comment: Note that the `global` trick used here won't work in ES5 strict mode.

Comment: @Reid: I'm not aware of that - could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: In this code, `this` refers to the global object (`window`). In strict mode, that's no longer the case: `this` when used like this will give `undefined` instead. If this anonymous function was executed in the context of another function, it would work, but `this` will never refer to the global object in strict mode (unless specifically bound).

Comment: For comparison: `(function () { return this; }());` returns `window`, while `(function () { 'use strict'; return this; }());` returns `undefined`.

Comment: Hi!
I usually add the "use strict"; because i want to catch any variables that leak out and as you said I am getting a "undefined" error... how do i correct that?

Comment: @Reid: I'm pretty sure that's just within a function. If you're in the global context, `this` still refers to the window object.

Comment: @patrick dw: That's true. The reason behind that is when the execution context of the global scope is set up, `this` is explicitly set to the global object (ECMA-262, §10.4.1.1). In non-strict mode, the `ThisBinding` of an execution context whose `ThisArg` is `null` or `undefined` is re-set to the global object (ECMA-262, §10.4.3). However, this action does not happen in strict mode (ECMA-262, Annex C). So, yes, `this` in the global execution context *does* evaluate to the global object... for what it's worth.

Answer (score 4):

In Javascript, a function can be stored in a variable (as it is an object basically).

You could do something like this using a closure:

```
(function (global) {

  global.something= function () {
      // do something, return something
  };

}(this));
```

Remember, if you write `()` after a function name, it means you're executing it. If you want to pass the function itself, you simply write its name.

Consider this example:

```
var x = something(); //x will hold the RETURN value of 'something'
var y = something; //y will hold a reference to the function itself
```

So after doing the 2nd example, you could do: `var x = y();` which will actually give you the same result if you just simply did the 1st example.

Comment: Hi, I edited my post, please look above. I am getting 2 errors: "global is undefined" (.js file) and "something is not defined" (html file)

Answer (score 1):

```
(function (global) {

  global.something = function()
  {
    // do something, return something
  }

}(this));
```

**Updated question:**

> `<body onload="javascript:something()">`

This won't work. Try this instead:

```
<body onload="something()">
```

Comment: Hi, I edited my post, please look above. I am getting 2 errors: "global is undefined" (.js file) and "something is not defined" (html file)

Comment: If global isn't defined, then your first code block that you said *is* working, would *not* work. So what is the code you had that actually works?

Comment: @Justin: Your `global` parameter is only available inside the function, so won't be available to the inline `onload`. Because you're assigning `something` to the global object, it should be available from the global `window`. `<body onload="something()">`